# Why am I seeing different Folder Names in Windows 10 when using File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10

Friends,

I'm puzzled by the behaviour I am seeing in Windows 10 File Explorer and why it is showing different names within file explorer. It will be easier to show rather than explain so here come several screen shots....

First one, the title bar and (I think it is called the address bar) are in sync and show the same location.

[image]

I navigate into the "Flowers" folder (or so I think it is called) and see that title bar and address bar now differ:

[image]

The title bar displays a location of C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Theme2 whilst the address bar displays Local Disk > Web > WallPaper > Flowers

At this point I would have expected to be in the Flowers Folder but I am in the Theme2 folder which up to this point didn't know existed!

When I navigate to the Folder using the command prompt I can see it is in fact Theme2  but I don't understand why.

[image]

I have searched and not finding any results makes me feel I am missing something!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the two `Theme` folders there is a file named `Desktop.ini` which has data for File Explorer on how to display information about this folder.

The Theme2 (Flowers) desktop.ini has this content:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\System32\themeui.dll,-2112
```

It points to a Windows DLL with a whole lot of strings in it, it asks for string with id 2112 which in English is `Flowers`, if you change to another language, it will display something else.

If you delete the Desktop.ini file, you will never see `Flowers` again, just Theme2.